# Deeplearning4j on spark: Is it possible to capture weights for each layer while training neural network

Tags: apache-spark, deep-learning, deeplearning4j, dl4j

I have been trying to find if there is a way to capture and save(as json) weights of each layer of neural network while training using DL4J(deeplearning4j on spark).

Please let me know if someone has any idea.

Answer (score 1):

During a training loop you get back a multilayernetwork from fit:
https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/blob/master/deeplearning4j-scaleout/spark/dl4j-spark/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/spark/impl/multilayer/SparkDl4jMultiLayer.java#L202

That's a local version of the model youc an do whatever you like with.
 See http://deeplearning4j.org/spark for more.